# Leased line Vs Broad Band connections

Tags: internet

I have a doubt,

What I have understood is that leased line would give full bandwidth for all computers placed in my network (under the firewall) If i am using Leased line connection in my office.
Which means If i have 10MBps leased line connection in my office  every each system will have full bandwidth 10MBps even if all systems access the internet at once.

But...

If its a 100Mbps Broad Band connection, the 100Mbps bandwidth will be shared for every each systems. lets say some systems will have good speed and some of the systems will have normal speed, and if all the systems access the internet at once the speed will be very low in Broad Band...

Is this correct ?? If this is correct please gimme some link where i can get the full details or else please give me the clarifications.

Thanks
Ansar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The bandwidth is that maximum amount of data that can be sent across a link per second. A 10 Mbps bandwidth on a link means that the aggregate bandwidth of all the hosts using the link is 10 Mbps, and it doesn't matter if the line is leased or not.

I think you are confusing terms. In a baseband connection, a frame crossing the link uses the full bandwidth of the link. That is like many forms of ethernet, e.g. 100BASE-TX (the BASE means baseband), where only one device at a time can send a frame. On the other hand, broadband means that there are multiple channels that can simultaneously carry frames across the link, e.g cable TV.

Unfortunately, the government has ignored these definitions, and it has determined that broadband means any link above a certain bandwidth, but in reality, the bandwidth doesn't determine if a link is baseband or broadband.

In any case, a leased line simply means that you have leased a physical connection from one endpoint to another endpoint. This is typically a private network connection between two of your sites, as opposed to a connection to the public Internet.

Answer (score 1):

With Leased Line Connection, lets say 100Mbps, you can download data with 100Mbs suppose you have one computer, and if you have 10 Computer, it will be shared, same with upload speed. but with Broadband Connection, generally they come with lesser upload speed generally 10% of Download Speed. so basically if you are uploading a large file, your network connection would be appeared slow, while download will be much faster, same concept here for shared bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

No, the speed of the link is the speed of the link. You won't get more than that total.

The difference between "leased line" and "broadband" connections is more subtle.

- leased line connections are usually symmetric while "broadband" connections are usually asymetric.
- broadband connections are usually priced at levels home users and small buisnesses can reasonablly afford. "leased lines" tend to cost considerbally more.
- With broadband connections you usually get the line and internet service as a package. With leased lines you can lease a line to an ISP and then seperately negotiate an Internet service contract.
- With broadband connections your service may be contended at the local level, with leased lines it's usually dedicated at least as far as the ISP (though no internet connection can really be truely uncontended).
- With leased lines you usually get a service level agreement which means that (in theory at least) if something goes wrong an engineer should be out to fix it quickly. With broadband connections you get very little guarantee of anything.

Comment: Contention is also dependent on broadband type. Adsl, sdsl, and fios usually are free of local contention. Cable operates off a regional pool. Cable also tends to be higher latency, though that has gotten better from the early days. Cable bandwidth also has a higher burst rate but less good sustained rates at higher latency. Latency is an issue for all broadband types, consumer more than business but that is vendor equipment driven.

Comment: It depends how local you are talking, cable usually has contention on the local loop, DSL has a dedicated local loop but can still have contention out of the local phone exchange. Leased lines are likely to be dedicated as far as the ISP pop.

Answer (score -1):

if you buy broadband or fibre you will find more ping and less speed if someone opens office near your office and buy the same broadband. the broadband is shared between offices and houses and they even sell bandwidth at night to some other country and your bandwidth becomes 1mbps only. so you will find a problem if some new building is made near you and they buy that broadband-only. in broadband others office can see your packet by using programs like wireshark and even steal passwords and can cause fake traffic in internet line.

if you buy a leased line, you will find more ping and less speed if your office(organization) gets more employee and more number of computers running together.

buying fibre or broadband is like renting a house which can be given to other country person at night. buying leased line is like buying a whole house only.

Comment: The question is not about ping or latency but about shared or dedicated bandwidth. Overprovisioning by the ISP is yet another topic and networks not under the OP's control are off-topic here anyway.